# 301 Redirect htaccess

Tags: php, .net, apache, .htaccess

im having a problem with my htaccess

I have the following

```
Redirect 301 /inspection-test.html http://www.newsit.co.uk/inspection-test.aspx
```

My current site runs on php and the new one runs on .net

The redirect works but its showing as

```
http://www.newsit.co.ukinspection-test.html
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [`RedirectMatch` <sup>**Apache HTTPD Docs**</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) instead:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/inspection-test\.html$ ttp://www.newsit.co.uk/inspection-test.aspx
```

[`Redirect` <sup>**Apache HTTPD Docs**</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) will add the original URL-part to the end of the redirect URL which produces the unexpected output in your case on your server.

With `RedirectMatch` you can better control the behavior.

Comment: Theres a lot of pages and all the url's differ?

Comment: Where is a lot of pages and how do the urls differ?

Answer (score 0):

Strange.

The url-part appended at the end of the path should only happen i your Redirect first argument is a directory, not for a file.

Now while you're testing the rewrites you shouldn't use **301** codes, as **your browser will store the 1st result** (so your first test) and will never ask the server for the fixed mapping (if you fix it). So it can be as well that you need to switch off your browser before redoing the redirect test. So maybe your rule is OK but your browser is not testing it.

While you're testing you should use **302** redirect codes.

> Theres a lot of pages and all the url's differ

You should study [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap). If you can list quite easily the old url and map each one to a new url url then a `txt:` map will dop the job, first with 302 codes, and when you're ok with it use a 301 code with a hash map file instead of a text one.

```
RewriteMap oldtonew txt:/path/to/my/hashmap/oldtonew.txt [NC]
# detect new url from map file
RewriteCond  ${oldtonew:%{REQUEST_URI}|NotFound}  !NotFound
RedirectRule .?  ${oldtonew:%{REQUEST_URI}}  [NC,R=301]
#no mapping
RewriteCond  ${oldtonew:%{REQUEST_URI}|NotFound}  NotFound
RedirectRule .?  http://www.example.com/notfound.html  [NC,R=301]
```

In oldtonew.txt write things like that

```
/inspection-test.html http://www.newsit.co.uk/inspection-test.aspx
/inspection-foo.html http://www.newsit.co.uk/inspection-bar.aspx
```

Else if you can express the old-to-new mapping with some keywords in the old url, the **DirectoryMatch** could maybe do the trick, or some mod-rewrite with the good extractions. But the faster solution is the rewriteMap with an hash file (dbm).

Finally If you can express your old-to-new url mapping only with a with a program (a database?) you'll have to use the `prg:` keyword (quite hard) in rewriteMap.