# redirect 301 to in htaccess is not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [htaccess 301 redirect not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117012/htaccess-301-redirect-not-working)

I need to redirect when some one want `test.php to newpage.php`.

My htaccess contains:

```
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^contact.shtml$ contact.php [NC]

RewriteRule ^news/(.*)/(.*)$ news_main.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]

Redirect /test.php http://mydomain.com/newpage.php
```

But it is not working. Is anything wrong here? If it us so please help me.

Comment: I don't see where you're trying to redirect. Why do you think your code should redirect?

Comment: Please double check with http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect - And place above the RewriteEngine section.

Comment: possible duplicate of [htaccess 301 redirect not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117012/htaccess-301-redirect-not-working) or [301 Redirect htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705873/301-redirect-htaccess)

Answer (score 2):

If the redirect is important, you should place it above the section that is related to the rewrite module.

Also if you want a 301 (Permanent) redirect, you need to specify it. By default, the redirect is 302.

Apart from that, everything looks right in my eyes.

```
# Core Module
Options All -Indexes

# Alias Module
Redirect 301 /test.php http://mydomain.com/newpage.php

# Rewrite Module
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^contact.shtml$ contact.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)/(.*)$ news_main.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly add code as follow in .htaccess file -

Redirect 301 /test.php http://mydomain.com/newpage.php